# How to play back raw audio stream?

Tags: java, android, audio, encoding, audiotrack

I receive a stream of audio data (one channel, 16000Hz, 170ms buffer) in my android app and I want to play this audio.
I discovered [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) but when I am playing the sound I only get loud and awkward sound.

My code so far looks like this:

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 128000, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
audioTrack.play();

while (true) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[32000];

    inputStream.readFully(buf);
    audioTrack.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

refer to this example: buf size needs to be carefull calculated based on your data, not necessarily random 32000.

```
int bufsize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
    8000, 
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
);
AudioTrack trackplayer = new AudioTrack(
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, 
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_ STEREO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
    bufsize, 
    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
);
trackplayer.play();
trackplayer.write(bytes_pkg, 0, bytes_pkg.length);
trackplayer.stop();
trackplayer.release();
```

Comment: Thank you. Now things I say (e.h. "Hello") are played back but there is an extremly high pitched buzzing sound too. My spoken words are in comparison with the buzzing very quite. What could be wrong there?

Comment: Be sure you match the samplerate and the number of channels (mono, stereo?) of the sound you are playing.